# What Survival Analysis model to use for event occurring multiple times?

Tags: survival

I have a dataset about when do people with genetically inherited disease have infections.

There are several variables like treatment type, placebo or not, age, sex etc.

I also have time to first infection, and time to every consecutive infection of the person, some of which are censored

I have to estimate hazard rate of infection. Should I consider those time intervals between consecutive infections of a person or should I take only time to first infection?

Thank you for attention